# How do I put a print statement on the same line as a return statement?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a print statement on the same line as the return statement, how do I go about doing this?

I have tried to put the print statement just under the if statement, but above return statements and it prints the result above the return statement.

```py
def isleap(y):
    if y % 400 == 0:
        print("Year %d is divisible by 400, therefore it is a leap year" %y)
        return True
    elif y % 100 ==0:
        return False
    elif y % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I am importing the above code to run from another file, which is this:

```
import leapyear
print (leapyear.isleap(1800))
print (leapyear.isleap(2019))
print (leapyear.isleap(2000))
print (leapyear.isleap(2012))
```

This is the result:

```
False
False
Year 2000 is divisible by 400, therefore it is a leap year
True
True
```

I want the result to have something like

> True: Year 2000 is divisible by 400, therefore it is a leap year

all in the same line, with the colon involved.

Comment: Why? It's just going to be less readable.

Comment: You could return a string that says exactly what you want instead of True, and drop the print statement inside the function

Comment: use `return True, success_message`

Comment: On closer reading, it looks like you're conflating the statements with the output they print (or the output that eventually comes from other code printing the returned value). Putting the statements on the same line is an entirely different thing from putting the output on one line.

Comment: @hadi, returns tuple; may not align with OP's requirement.

Comment: @user2357112 my homework required it. got the answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def isleap(y):
    if y % 400 == 0:
        return True, ': Year %d is divisible by 400, therefore it is a leap year' %y 
    elif y % 100 ==0:
        return False, ''
    elif y % 4 == 0:
        return True, ''
    else:
        return False, ''


print(*isleap(1800), sep='')
print(*isleap(2019), sep='')
print(*isleap(2000), sep='')
print(*isleap(2012), sep='')


print()


# If you want to use it later.
ret = isleap(2000)
if ret[0]:
    print('Length of the message is:', len(ret[1]))
```

Output:

```
False
False
True: Year 2000 is divisible by 400, therefore it is a leap year
True

Length of the message is: 60
```

---

After I answered this question, the person who asked this question asked what to do if he/she wants to reuse the results. Hence, I have updated my answer which is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355231/5099803) answer.

Comment: If you have used my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355231/8973620) in your edited answer you could at least upvote mine.

Comment: I have added the link to your solution in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can `return True` and the print statement together. With the help of the star `*` operator you can pass elements from the tuple to the `print()` function as separate parameters:

```
def func():
    return True, 'It works.'

print(*func())
# True It works.
```

If the order of print statements is not important you can add the parameter `end=''` to the first `print()` function:

```
def func():
    print('It works.', end='')
    return True

print(func())
# It works.True
```